# Photoshop groups not behaving correctly on mac

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use photoshop on a mac once a week at my college class and find that the group layers function does not work like on my PC.

When I group up some layers I can move them all at once just fine, but when I try to move them on their own, it snaps back to moving them as a group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the layers are not linked and you are you have the auto-select in "layer" and not group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move single layer, make this sure you have turned on Auto select with layers only, if its selected  with group, it will move the whole group while any layer selected, may be this is what you are facing right now...

[image]